# How to calculate position based on click in div

Tags: javascript, math

I have a div with a width of 308px. In this div I have a buffer bar (which can be any length from 0 to 308).

The div is used to show the progress of a playing audio track. The audio track has a duration in milliseconds.

I am trying to enable the user to change the position in the track based on a click in the div. However my math is all wrong.

What I currently have is:

```
var pos = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left; // returns the position of the click in the div (0 to 380)
var relpos = parseInt(308, 10)/parseInt(pos, 10);
var newpos = parseInt(duration, 10)/parseInt(relpos, 10);
```

How to calculate the new position based on the position of the click on the div?

I've setup a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/xCUZZ/) if you want to test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First the 308 is actualy the buffer width you should replace that if you need to resize.
The code is:

```
  (function($) {
    var duration = 138736;
    $(document).on('click', '.buffer', function(e) {
    var pos = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
    var relpos = duration*pos;
    var newpos = relpos/308;

    $('.test').html(pos + '/' + newpos + '/'  + duration);
  });
  })(jQuery);
```

if      308  is  duration
than    pos  is  x, x = (pos * duration) / 308

Comment: I choose to NOT pay attention in school. Who needs math anyway right? ;) Thanks!